# What is the corresponding TCP states for states in iptables? (NEW and ESTABLISHED)

Tags: networking, iptables, tcp

The iptables manual says

> ESTABLISHED meaning that the packet is associated with a connection which has seen packets in both directions, NEW meaning that the packet has started a new connection, or otherwise associated with a connection which has not seen packets in both directions

This is unclear to me. My understanding is

For the server:

- on receiving an incoming SYN packet, iptables think it's NEW in the PREROUTING chain.
- on receiving the SYN+ACK packet, it's established in the PREROUTING chain.

For the client:

- on sending the SYN packet, it's NEW in the OUTPUT chain
- on receiving the SYN+ACK packet, it remains NEW
- on sending the ACk packet, it's ESTABLISHED in the OUTPUT chain.

Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out

For the server:

- on receiving an incoming SYN packet, iptables think it's NEW in the PREROUTING chain.
- on sending the SYN+ACK packet, it's ESTABLISHED in the POSTROUTING chain.

For the client:

- on sending the SYN packet, it's NEW in the POSTROUTING chain
- on receiving the SYN+ACK packet, it is ESTABLISHED in the PREROUTING chain.

The concept of ESTABLISHED in conntrack/iptables is different from the TCP which requires the 3rd handshake. That's why it's confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

Packets in a RELATED or ESTABLISHED state are those which belong to an
already opened connection. You'll generally want to accept them, otherwise
connections will get established correctly but nothing will be able to flow
after the initial handshake.

In other words, this is Linux saying: this incoming packet is a response
to a legitimate request from our own host, so let it thru.

If you wish to understand the flow more thoroughly, see
[this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/833966/18736).